# What should I do about SQL connections that is a Head Blocker?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking at the Activity Monitor in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

I see that a lot of processes indicates that it is a blocking process, by the value of 1 in the Head Blocker column.

Is this normal, or am I potentially dealing with an issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, not normal

The locks causing the blocking will usually be held because of

- inadvertent open transaction (ie not committed or rolled back)
- long running transaction/statement (eh a delete taking hours)
- client command timeout without SET XACT_ABORT

You could [KILL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) the offending spid but this fixes the symptom not the cause

A very useful script to start finding out what is wrong: [open transactions with text and plans](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Script-open-transactions-with-text-and-plans.aspx):

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is an issue. You have some transaction(s) holding locks longer than you would like, perhaps the holder went out to lunch?